# Coordinate Reference System issues between SHP and Raster file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am having an issue with the CRS of a given Aster DEM.
I have downloaded a Aster DEM from www.oziexplorer3.com which comes with the EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 as the CRS.

This is a DEM from Gabon, and all the other data I have for the project I am working on has the CRS defined as EPSG:32632 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N.

I have to create some contours from the DEM in order to use them in another software for the elevation definition of a water network. When I open the DEM and SHPs I have in QGis they perfectly overlap (although they have different CRS) and so do the contours I extract from the DEM.

But then, when I import the contours into the other software, because they have different CRS, they do not overlap and so I can't use the newly created contours in order to define the water network's elevations... and if I change the CRS in QGis (for the DEM or for the contours) they do not overlap even in QGIS...

Is there a solution for this problem?

PS - please know that I am quite inexperienced with GIS softwares, but you might already noticed that...

Comment: Is on-the-fly transformation enabled in QGIS? You can check that in Settings->options->crs

Comment: Yes it is on... I guess this is why I can see the overlapped shp and DEM even though they have not the same CRS...

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do calculations I would go to the trouble of reprojecting your data.  Since the majority of your data are in EPSG:32632, I would use the Raster->Projections->Warp tool to create a new version of your DEM in EPSG:32632.  The tool is built on the GDAL tool of the same name whose documentation is [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html).  Don't let the documentation put you off as the plugin GUI is fairly self explanatory.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your reply, i'll try to do as you tell me...

Comment: Dear Mappagnosis I have used the Warp tool and it worked perfectly. I just have one question, do you recommend any specific resampling method?

Comment: Your choice can depend on what your data represent as well on the speed/quality of processing you require.  there are a number of discussion on that question on this board (e.g. [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2587/how-do-you-decide-what-interpolation-method-to-use-for-resampling-raster-data))

Answer (score 0):

I guess your mistake is in `and if I change the CRS in QGis`.

If you do this with `Set CRS for Layer`, your data gets corrupt. You change the CRS, but the coordiantes won't get reprojected.

To do it right, set the CRS back to the original value, then rightclick -> `Save As ...` to another file name, and the target CRS. If you check `add result to canvas` it will be placed same as the original. But when you turn `On -the-fly-reprojection **OFF**, the reprojected layer should still stay in the right place.