# Making meter and Arcmin based raster compatible for analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to work with temperature and precipitation data from worldclim (Bioclim) and the Corine Land Cover data. however, the rasters are in two different grid sizes and formats, 2.5 Arc Min and 100m respectively. I need to know how to convert one grid format into the other or some way of analysing using both rasters if possible.I know arc mins are not exactly a straight forward size and it is dependent on the latitude so I am not sure what to do.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

If the CORINE data is in a reasonable coordinate reference system for analysis, project the bioclim data to the same coordinate reference system.

If necessary, clip the bioclim data to your area of interest before you project it.

You can either specify the output cell size or let the Project Raster tool calculate it for you. It will be larger than 100x100 m so you should resample to CORINE data to match it.

Somewhat related: [Converting worldclim data to 30m resolution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137932/converting-worldclim-data-to-30m-resolution)