# Removing every second row and column cells from a raster file

Tags: dem, topography, gis-principle

I have a SRTM 3 arc second topography model (.tif file).
If I remove every second row and column of cells from the grid, can it be said that the model becomes a 6 arc second?

Or does SRTM 3 arc second model needs some kind of interpolation of its grid in order to get the 6 arc second model?
If it does need, can anyone provide GDAL string example of how this can be done?

Comment: No, you have to resample it to new cell size

Comment: @FelixIP Removing every other row and column *is* resampling (it's an instance of the nearest-neighbor algorithm).

Comment: Thank you for the replies both FelixIP and whuber.
@whuber: So can a 3 arc second model be considered to be a 6 arc second model if every other row and column is removed?

Comment: Of course--the spacing is now twice 3 arc-seconds, right?  For many purposes this approach (nearest-neighbor resampling) isn't a great choice, though.  You might consider availing yourself of other resampling options.  [Cubic convolution](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2587) is attractive in this setting.

Comment: Thank you @whuber. I took a look at both the linked topic and your article at quantdec.com.
Yes, the spacing is twice 3 arc-seconds, and it has about 4 times less cells than 3 arc-seconds.
So "manual" (sort to say) interpolation in this way (removing every second row and column of cells from the grid) can basically produce a 6 arc-seconds DEM from 3 arc-seconds DEM? This is what I want to know.
Regardless if this approach is more appropriate/precise than using some other resampling methods (like cubic convolution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want means doubling the pixel size by using nearest neighbor resampling. The shortest GDAL command for doing that is

```
gdal_translate -outsize 50% 0 input.tif output.tif
```

Read the manual http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html because otherwise you can't know what `-outsize 50% 0` does nor that `-r` is not needed because nearest is the default resampling algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for the help @user30184 .
I am aware of the gdal_translate page. Sometimes I feel like both gdal_translate and gdalwarp pages have been deliberately written to repel any gdal beginner users. That's how they have been written.

Would you mind if I ask you whether or not the Gdal resampling you presented is the same as removing every second row and column of cells from the grid?